# redirect an image link to a php page (image name has space)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect this link (the image name is actually `pantone purple.jpg`)

```
http://www.example.com/images/pantone%20purple.jpg
```

to this

```
http://www.example.com/colorcharts.php
```

I have tried this code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/images/(\d+)-(.+)\.(png|gif|jpe?g|bmp)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.example.com/colorcharts.php
```

Comment: tried this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^images/(\d+).*\.jpg$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.example.com/colorcharts.php`    still not working :/

Comment: yes, because `\d` means digits. `pantone` has no digits...

Comment: umm @starkeen who what do i do now? what will be correct code?

Comment: ah yeah. shoot. got confused with rewriterule - that doesn't have the leading `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^image/pantone\spurple\.jpg$ http://www.example.com/colorcharts.php [NC,L,R]
```

\s means 1 space in regex, this matches %20 in the request.

Comment: oh man yeah!!! you are my hero! it is working! only the folder is "images" :) so switched image to images!!! Thank You so so so much! thanks also for explaining stuff with your replies, i am saving every solution in a text file for later reference it is really helping tons!

Comment: This redirect is applied only when the user visits the link directly in the browser? I mean, the image can be used in ```<img src="">```?